# Sort div by calculating ids value by jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

This is my current html structure.

```
<div id="eventContainer">
  <div id="10_10_am" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="08_30_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="09_00_am" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="04_00_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="10_30_am" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="09_30_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
</div>
```

I want to sort it based on div ids which are nothing but formatted time like `10_10_am` means `10:10 am`.
The structure I want is :

```
<div id="eventContainer">
  <div id="09_00_am" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="10_10_am" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="10_30_am" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="04_00_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
  <div id="08_30_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>  
  <div id="09_30_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer"> some data... </div>
</div>
```

How can I calculate theses ids and sort accordingly?

Comment: Why are they not ordered properly in the first place?

Comment: Actually, there will be multiple time values for single record and I have to display data based on time value. so I can not sort it properly, like if I sort on time1 value then within same record there may be time2 value which may be pm time. So can not sort it from back end.

Comment: I Think, You can Do this 
1. Fetch all the div is convert it into dataformat and then to unixtime stamp.
2. Apply the sort function on this new array 
{'09_00_am':UnixTimeStampOf09_00_am,... }
3. then with reference of the keys like 09_00_am, you can rearrage the divs

Comment: I would be trying to leverage a back-end algorithm to sort them before you output them to HTML - you could write a sorting algorithm (bubble sort, heap sort or whatever) to do it, but I don't see messing around with it client-side being very efficient. Surely your back-end code must generate these divs based on some logic? Use that logic to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a solution for your problem. Please do look at the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/9unts/

```
var sortFunction=function(){
var id;
for(i=0;i<$('#eventContainer').children().length;i++){
    id=$('#eventContainer').children().eq(i).attr('id');
    new_id=formatId(id);
    if(id.indexOf('am')!=-1){
        time_in_am.push(new_id);
    }else{
        time_in_pm.push(new_id);
    }
}
time_in_am.sort();
time_in_am.reverse();
time_in_pm.sort();
time_in_pm.reverse();

for(j=0;j<time_in_pm.length;j++){
    $('#'+deFormatId(time_in_pm[j])+'_pm').prependTo('#eventContainer');
}
for(k=0;k<time_in_am.length;k++){
    $('#'+deFormatId(time_in_am[k])+'_am').prependTo('#eventContainer');
}
};
```

Lemme know if it help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken all the `id's of the div` in `myArray` and then convert it into `24 hour format` (eg. `10_10_am to 1010 and 09_30_pm to 2130`) using function `am_pm_to_hours` than sorted array using function `sortmyway` than converted back `hours_am_pm` to get than sorted div id back (eg `1010 to 10_10_am and 2130 to 09_30_pm`) and than append  sorted array in `div id eventContainer`.

## **HTML**

```
    <div id="eventContainer">
        <div id="10_10_am" class="eventbytimeContainer">some data...id:10_10_am</div>
        <div id="08_30_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer">some data...id:08_30_pm</div>
        <div id="09_00_am" class="eventbytimeContainer">some data...id:09_00_am</div>
        <div id="04_00_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer">some data...id:04_00_pm</div>
        <div id="10_30_am" class="eventbytimeContainer">some data...id:10_30_am</div>
        <div id="09_30_pm" class="eventbytimeContainer">some data...id:09_30_pm</div>
    </div>
```

## **js**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function am_pm_to_hours(time) {
        var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
        var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
        var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
        if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
        if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
        var sHours = hours.toString();
        var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
        if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
        if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
        return (sHours + sMinutes);
    }

    function hours_am_pm(time) {
        var hours = time[0] + time[1];
        var min = time[2] + time[3];
        if (hours < 12) {
            return hours + '_' + min + '_am';
        } else {
            return hours-12 + '_' + min + '_pm';
        }
    }
    myArray = [];
    $('#eventContainer .eventbytimeContainer').each(function () {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        var n = id.split("_");
        time = am_pm_to_hours(n[0] + ':' + n[1] + ':' + ' ' + n[2]);
        myArray.push(time);
    });
    console.log(myArray);

    function sortmyway(data_A, data_B) {
        return (data_A - data_B);
    }
    myArray.sort(sortmyway);

    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i] = hours_am_pm(myArray[i]);
    }

    $.each(myArray, function (index, value) {
        if(value.length == 7){
            value = '0'+value;
        }
        $('#eventContainer').append($('#'+value));
    });
});
```

Working Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5c83m/1/